# How can I make one chart "span" the height / width of multiple charts in concatenated plots?

Tags: python, altair

In the following example, I'd like to have `exp` fill the entire width of the plot (so, as wide as `sin` and `cos` combined).  By default, `exp` fills only one column.

How can I do this, ideally using some "auto" setting (without explicitly setting a `width=` to a number)?

```py
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
source = pd.DataFrame({
  'x': x,
  'sin': np.sin(x),
  'cos': np.cos(x),
  'exp': np.exp(x),
})

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(x='x')
sin = base.encode(y='sin')
cos = base.encode(y='cos')
exp = base.encode(y='exp')
(sin | cos) & exp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no way of automatically specifying the size of a chart to fill the entire layout of multiple concatenated charts (but if you find one it could help solve part of https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7194).

If you want to avoid manually estimating a number, you could compute the the height programatically by accessing the height of each chart object and adding 60 pixels for each level of concatenation (I include a breakdown of where most of these 60 pixels come from in the code below). This is naturally not as convenient as an `"auto"` value, but maybe it is at least somewhat helpful.

**Unfortunately this is not as straightforward for the width, since this depends on the number of digits in the y-axis of all charts in the top row of concatenation (except the left most chart, which expands the ticklabels into the padding space to the left without increasing the overall width of the figure).**

```
height = (
    sin.to_dict()['config']['view']['continuousHeight']  # 300
    + exp.to_dict()['config']['view']['continuousHeight']  # 300
    + 5  # The default bottom padding of chart top-left chart
    + 5  # The default top padding of the bottom-left chart
    + 11  # The default x-axis labels font size (+padding?) of the top-left chart
    + 15  # The default x-axis title font size (+padding?) of the top-left chart
    + 20  # The default spacing between concatenated charts
    + 3  # Not sure where these are from
)

# Notice that the concatenation ordering is different to avoid empty space under the `sin` plot
(sin & exp) | cos.properties(height=height)
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful!  Thank you.  Maybe the 20px unaccounted for are the height of the x-axis title ("x") of top-left.

A very unfortunate limitation.  Guessing there's no way to get or set the total chart size (and not just of content)?  I saw a `AutoSizeParams` setting of `"padding"` which sounded promising ("includes the padding within the view size calculations, such that the width and height settings indicate the total intended size of the view"), but I haven't figured out how to use it here.

Comment: @capitalistcuttle Good point, both the x-axis labels and the x-axis title font sizes would contribute to the gap (and there seems to be some padding also, I updated my answer with the more precisely estimated numbers, now there are only 3 pixels missing!). I am not sure whether the autosizing would help here or if that is mostly useful in terms of fitting the entire plot inside a HTML contains element.

Answer (score 0):

A similar *solution* for width:

```
w = 200
spacing = 64

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(x='x')
sin = base.encode(y='sin').properties(width=w, height=100)
cos = base.encode(y='cos').properties(width=w, height=100)
exp = base.encode(y='exp').properties(width=2*w+spacing, height=100)

row = alt.hconcat(sin, cos).properties(
    bounds='flush',
    spacing=spacing
)
                  
alt.vconcat(row, exp).configure_axisY(labelLimit=spacing)
```

[image: chart]

Not aligned, but maybe visually nice enough with less code:

```
w = 200

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(x='x')
sin = base.encode(y='sin').properties(width=w, height=100)
cos = base.encode(y='cos').properties(width=w, height=100)
exp = base.encode(y='exp').properties(width=2*w, height=100)

row = alt.hconcat(sin, cos)
alt.vconcat(row, exp).properties(center=True)
```

[image: chart2]